# Could I use aluminum foil as a ground plane for 1.4 GHz antenna?

Tags: antenna, ground-plane

I'm currently attempting to make a radio telescope that works at 1.4 GHz. Would household aluminum foil work as a ground plane? I saw someone asking the same thing for a 900 MHz antenna and I was wondering whether the same would hold true for an antenna working at this frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aluminium has at 1400 MHz skin depth about 2.1 micrometrs. I guess your foil is at least 4 times thicker, so it works. Some ineffectivity could be measured if your foil were thinner than the skin depth.

Learn the "skin effect" which qualitatively says that only quite thin area on well conducting metal surface has some effect at microwave frequencies.

Start from this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect

The effect has easy to use formulas if one wants quantitative measures.